# What can cause flyway to not auto-detect migrations at startup, but then be able to do so at runtime?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, jvm, flyway, micronaut

#### Question:

**What can cause flyway to not auto-detect migrations from the default path, and prevent resolution of migrations from a custom location, during startup only?**

Given the following:

- `io.micronaut.flyway:micronaut-flyway` uses `flyway 6.4.4`
- Flyway, when run at application startup by micronaut, is unable to auto-detect migrations
- Flyway, when run during bean initialization (i.e. in the constructor of the controller bean), **is able to auto-detect migrations**
- Flyway is able to pick up and apply the migrations during startup during integration-testing. This gives me confidence that it is configured correctly. I can break it in expected ways by messing with the config / file location.
- Migration file is certainly on the classpath during runtime on prod at the expected location, as evidenced by runtime-logs.

#### Context

I want to setup flyway migrations for my Kotlin-Micronaut-GoogleCloudFunction. As described in the docs, I have my migrations under `src/main/resources/db/migration`, named like `V1__create_xyz_table.sql`.

I verified that the migration is on the classpath at runtime, by logging it in the function body:

```kotlin
val fileContent = FunctionController::class.java.getResource("/db/migration/V1__create_xyz_table.sql").readText()   
println(fileContent) // "create table xyz(id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)"
```

This works, and logs the contents of the file to stdout as expected.

**My integration tests run fine. Migrations are automatically detected and applied to the mysql-testcontainer instance. Data is written to and read from the dockerized DB.**

However, when I start the application locally, or deploy it, the application warns me:

`No migrations found. Are your locations set up correctly?`

Unsurprisingly, triggering the function results in errors like "Table xyz does not exist".

Besides the actual db-credentials, my test and production setup share the following config:

```yaml
# application.yml
datasources:
  mysql:
    url: <url>
    username: <user>
    password: <pw>
flyway:
  datasources:
    mysql:
      enabled: true
```

#### Other things I have tried:

- Using a Java-Based migration (same result)
- Using the custom locations config (same result)

#### What "works":

- When I autowire the datasource into the function controller, and apply the migrations inside the constructor it works: `Successfully validated 1 migration.`

```kotlin
init {
  Flyway.configure().dataSource(mysqlDS).load().migrate()
}
```

This confirms, that all the necessary files are present and discoverable by flyway. Why would this not work during application startup?

I attached a debugger and found that different ClassLoaders are used to discover the resources:

- During startup: AppClassLoader
- During function execution: FunctionClassLoader

Comment: Are your migration configs being included in your generated `.jar` file?

Comment: What do you mean by migration configs? Afaik application.yaml has to be present for the app to start, and the *.sql files I'm able to log from the classpath, so they must be there aswell.

Comment: `"Afaik application.yaml has to be present for the app to start"` - It doesn't.

Comment: I should clarify... It is entirely possible that there is something in your app that might cause it to not start without an `application.yml`, but that isn't a requirement in general.  Many Micronaut services don't have one.

Comment: For the config items to have effect (i.e. the database-credentials which are used to connect to the DB) wouldnt it have to be within the jar?

Comment: Not necessarily, but if it were coming from someplace else (OS environment variables, runtime system properties, external config files, distributed config server) you would probably know about that.

Comment: Yes, they are only within application.yml.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Debugging, I realized that [the method that triggers the flyway](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-flyway/blob/267e97f999d20871317c5de3d8504ac1c792ce81/flyway/src/main/java/io/micronaut/flyway/DataSourceMigrationRunner.java#L55-L69) migration wasn't running. This method lives inside a Micronaut `BeanCreatedEventListener` which listens on the creation of `DataSource` type beans.

What left me scratching my head was that the `DataSource` type bean was created successfully, which I confirmed on runtime by fetching it from the application context. So why wasn't the even listener triggering?

This is because the bean was being created before the event listener was even initialized. Why was this happening? Because I had another custom even listener in my app that injected a `Jdbi` bean. The jdbi bean subsequently injected the DataSource bean. This means that my custom event listener was injecting the DataSource bean, so it was impossible for it to be initialized before the bean was created.

I suggest setting a breakpoint [in this method](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-flyway/blob/267e97f999d20871317c5de3d8504ac1c792ce81/flyway/src/main/java/io/micronaut/flyway/DataSourceMigrationRunner.java#L55-L69) to check if it's being triggered. If it's not, it's possible the cause of your issue was similar to mine.